# Are winter tires required in Turkey in December?

Tags: driving, turkey

I am going on my first trip to Turkey in 3 days and will be renting a car for some trips from the Sabiha Gocken airport to Istanbul and then from the city towards the cable car area in Bursa.

On the rental car form it asked if snow tires are required but it was optional leading me to believe they may not be mandated by law (otherwise they would be included in the rental charge).

Would I need snow tires?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Winter tires are obligatory for vehicles carrying goods and passengers for commercial purposes from December 1 to April 1. But the governors have the authority to make it obligatory in the provincial borders for automobiles according to the weather conditions.

http://www.ahaber.com.tr/otomobil/2016/11/30/kis-lastigi-kimlere-zorunlu-nasil-secilir-takmamanin-cezasi-ne-kadar-hangi-illerde-zorunlu

Comment: Does this mean there are check posts at the provinces?

Comment: Ken's answer is right, too. Traffic policemen may check your car. Becasue you must have chains on snowy days or when the roads are iced.

Answer (score 1):

Not winter tires but you  must have chains for the tires in the car just in case...